# My Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop due to the incompatibility with nvidia driver

Tags: 16.04, nvidia-geforce

I reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04, then installed nvidia-current and run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg`

rebooted and gets stuck in a login loop. My graphic card is **GeForce 6150SE nForce 430**. Can some help me solve the issue?

Comment: @Fabby I have read that post and can't fix the issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, tell us exactly what you tried and how it failed so we can help you further.

Comment: @Fabby I followed the instruction in the first answer, and the last thing I could do was to reinstall the system, but it did not work .

Comment: Try [this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics) next and feed back.

Comment: Nvidia nForce 430 is legacy hardware for which Nvidia no longer has a recommended Linux driver version . If it works with the default open-source drive I suggest you keep it as is.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Of course it does not work with the default driver. Does this mean that I should buy a new computer in order to use Linux?

Comment: @tmpbin It depends on your definition of "not working". Does it have video but performs poorly? It's working the best it can. No video? You have a problem indeed. If the motherboard supports a discrete graphics card buy the cheapest one you can find (a used one at eBay if it must be) and you'll get a few more years out of it.

Comment: @tmpbin I forgot to mention that Ubuntu (Unity), Kubuntu (KDE), Ubuntu GNOME or any other flavor with a modern desktop environment won't work either way because the system requirements are way higher than what an almost 20 years old hardware can provide. You may still have a chance with Lubuntu (LXDE) and if that fails try Puppy Linux.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Do you mean that nForce 430 is almost 20 years old? It surprises me.

Comment: @tmpbin https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Nvidia_nForce_chipsets#nForce4 (October 2004) so yes, I exaggerated a bit. But it's obsolete anyway and even when released it was just entry level hardware.

Answer (score 3):

Nvidia nForce 430 (GeForce 6150SE graphics) is [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Nvidia_nForce_chipsets#nForce4) hardware for which Nvidia no longer has a recommended Linux driver version. On top of that it was just entry level hardware at the time of its release, meant to office tasks and not much else.

Keeping the default open-source `nouveau` driver is recommended but not enough, a light Desktop Environment (e.g. LXDE in Lubuntu) is also required because the hardware is incompatible with any modern 3D DE like Unity, KDE or Gnome.

For better performance a cheap discrete graphics card can be added.