# What are the issues that make Ubuntu 18.04 gets stuck in a login loop?

Tags: 18.04, permissions, login, login-screen

Yesterday,I was configuring Java Path for installing [Netbeans Apache](https://netbeans.apache.org/),then I went to sleep.Today,when I'm trying to login with correct username and password ,the screen gets stuck to display login again.
I tried all the answers:

[Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

[My Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop due to the incompatibility with nvidia driver [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/845846/my-ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop-due-to-the-incompatibility-with-nvidia-driv)

The result of  `sudo cat .xsession-errors` is :

```
Xsession: X session started for root at Sat Feb  9 16:49:52 CET 2019
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/alaeddine/.Xauthority
localuser:root being added to access control list
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_GID=1000
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting MAIL=/var/mail/root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USER=root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting HOME=/home/alaeddine
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT4_IM_MODULE=xim
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-1YeMPItkMC,guid=70b8a7d6bd2d984b274e80eb5c5ef6a2
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_UID=1000
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LOGNAME=root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting TERM=linux
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USERNAME=root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting WINDOWPATH=2
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANG=en_US.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/alaeddine/.Xauthority
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_COMMAND=/usr/bin/startx
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHELL=/bin/bash
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_USER=alaeddine
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GPG_AGENT_INFO=/home/alaeddine/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.2
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PWD=/home/alaeddine
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
```

[steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver)
 said in this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079207/ubuntu18-04-1-lts-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) that the PATH is housed ,but I did not get what I do because it does not provide a full response.

Comment: I think your situation is different (the only reference to PATH in your .xsession-errors is `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin` which looks OK to me). Did you **need** to use `sudo` to `cat` the file? is so, it would point to an issues with the file or parent directory ownership/permissions.